# Different cells in tableview swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

example [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cORc.png

1. how to make the following table correctly
   I do not want crutches
   All cells one by one, except for a block of X.count, there will be a different number (from two or more)
2. how to find out the first and last cells from Block X later to show or hide the strip between the cells (between the points, I make their three thin ones, and want to hide or show the cell depending on the cell)

---

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class TableVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var loadingView: UIView!


    var number: String! = "number"

    var detail_data: DetailListData?







    var token: String?
    var json = "Invalid"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        loadingView.isHidden = false

        print("===============================",number!)

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HeaderTVC", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HeaderTVC")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DistanceTVC", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DistanceTVC")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MapTVC", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MapTVC")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "InfoTVC", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "InfoTVC")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BottomTVC", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BottomTVC")

        tableView.delegate = self

        token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token")! as? String

        getData()
    }

    func getData () {

        let httpHeaders = ["Authorization": token!,
                           "Accept": "application/json"]

        Alamofire.request(REST_API.MAIN_URL_DEV + REST_API.SHIPMENTS + "/" + number! ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: httpHeaders)
            .responseString { response in

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    self.json = JSON

                    //                    print(JSON)

                    if let jsonObj = self.json.parseJSONString {

                        if let data = jsonObj as? NSDictionary {

                            if let obj = DetailListJson4Swift_Base(dictionary: data) {


                                if obj.status?.code == 200 {

                                    self.detail_data = obj.data


                                    print("////====================  DATA", obj.data!, self.detail_data!)


                                    self.loadingView.isHidden = true

                                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                                } else {

                                    print("Status: Error code")
                                    MyAlertController.doAlert("Error", alertMessage: "something wrong, try again late")
                                }

                            } else {
                                MyAlertController.doAlert("Error", alertMessage: "Unable to construct movie object")
                                print("Unable to construct movie object")
                            }

                        } else {
                            MyAlertController.doAlert("Error", alertMessage: "Unable to interpret parsed object as dictionary")
                            print("Unable to interpret parsed object as dictionary")
                            print(jsonObj)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func accept(_ sender: Any) {


    }
}


extension TableVC {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if detail_data != nil {

            if section == 0 {

                return 3

            } else if section == 1 {


                return (detail_data?.waypoints?.count)!
            } else if section == 2 {


                return 1
            }

        }
        return 0
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            let headerTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderTVC", for: indexPath) as! HeaderTVC

            headerTVC.code.text = detail_data?.id!
            headerTVC.price.text = detail_data?.price?.total!
            headerTVC.distamce.text = detail_data?.distance!
            return headerTVC

        }


        if indexPath.row == 1 {

            let distanceTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DistanceTVC", for: indexPath) as! DistanceTVC



            return distanceTVC
        }

        if indexPath.row == 2 {

            let mapTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MapTVC", for: indexPath) as! MapTVC


            return mapTVC
        }

        if indexPath.row == 4 {

            let bottomTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BottomTVC", for: indexPath) as! BottomTVC



            return bottomTVC
        }



        // the other cells should contains title and subtitle:
        let infoTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InfoTVC", for: indexPath) as! InfoTVC


        return infoTVC
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Comment: Please show your tried code

Comment: @Lalitkumar
added

Comment: Why do you forced **unwrap** an optional and then cast it down to an optional? That's nonsensical.

Comment: @vadian This is not important at this moment
I asked about cell and tableview